# User to append only before/after div with specific class name

Tags: jquery

I have a drag and drop append event which creates a new marker on a page:

```
function appendReservedDropMarker(builderShowcase, e) {
  const reservedDropMarkerClass = '.reserved-drop-marker';
  $(builderShowcase.document.body).find(reservedDropMarkerClass).remove();
  $(e.target).append("<p class='reserved-drop-marker'></p>");
}
```

The page looks likes this:

```
<div class="box">
  <app-builder-navbar></app-builder-navbar>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <app-builder-hero></app-builder-hero>
</div>
```

I only want the user to be able to append before/after the box element. At the moment, when the component renders, they have scope to create a new marker anywhere.

Comment: Use `.parents()` with `e.target` to check if it's in a `.box` element.